# I use NAudio for split live audio after 5 minute but I unable to split from live source

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        record.Enabled = false;
        record.Enabled = true;



        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");

        waveSource = new WaveIn();
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

        waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);


        waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);


        //var dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        //Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        //File.WriteAllLines(dir + @"\myFile.txt", lines);

        waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"E:\"+ dt + ".wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);

        waveSource.StartRecording();

        record.Enabled = false;
    }

    void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
        }
    }



private void split_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mp3Path = @"E:\bulleya-w.mp3";
        int splitLength = 120; // seconds

        var mp3Dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(mp3Path);
        var mp3File = Path.GetFileName(mp3Path);
        var splitDir = Path.Combine(mp3Dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mp3Path));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(splitDir);

        int splitI = 0;
        int secsOffset = 0;

        using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3Path))
        {
            FileStream writer = null;
            Action createWriter = new Action(() =>
            {
                writer = File.Create(Path.Combine(splitDir, Path.ChangeExtension(mp3File, (++splitI).ToString("D4") + ".mp3")));
            });

            Mp3Frame frame;
            while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
            {
                if (writer == null) createWriter();

                if ((int)reader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds - secsOffset >= splitLength)
                {
                    // time for a new file
                    writer.Dispose();
                    createWriter();
                    secsOffset = (int)reader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds;
                }

                writer.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }

            if (writer != null) writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the best question ever in SO !

Comment: If only it contained an actual question...